# How to configure PyCharm to keep tabs organized in a user-defined place

Tags: linux, pycharm

PyCharm has 3 tabs on the left by default: `1:Project`, `2:Favorites`, `7:Structure`. The tab `1:Project` is in the top left corner, while the other two are in the bottom left corner.

I prefer having all 3 tabs next to each other in the top left corner. I can drag them from where they are to my preferred position. However, when I restart PyCharm they return to their default locations.

I've tried `Window -> Save Current Layout As Default` but that doesn't seem to affect the tabs.

Is there a way to persist my preferred tab layout?

Comment: The [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html) says : "return to the saved workspace layout by choosing *Window | Restore Default Layout* (Shift+F12)".

Comment: I tested this just now: (1) I closed and reopened PyCharm; (2) I moved the Favorites tab to the top left from bottom left; (3) Window -> Save Layout as Default; (4) Window -> Restore Layout (Shift+F12) - no change to the layout occurs when I do this; then (5) I restart PyCharm. The favorites tab is at the bottom left.

Comment: You do have a problem ...